# ANDing isolated power supplies

Tags: power-supply, isolation, poe

Is there any specific challenge to ANDing two isolated power supplies, assuming that ideal diodes are used on their outputs? I'm interested in making a particularly compact PoE supply capable of delivering ~50W, but size and design time are constrained, and the transformers seem to become larger / more custom in the reference designs capable of delivering these levels of power.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "ANDing" here? You only want an output if both supplies are switched on?

Comment: Reminds me of the time Linus tried to do whole house PC water cooling. Rather than just get a radiator from a wrecking yard *that already had 12V electric fans attached to it and is made to be outdoors*... Linus got a dozen individual PC cooling fans and lashed them together with zip ties. Total gong show, and of course it failed and Linus tore the whole system out.  And then tried again 2 years later. Maybe finally figured out where a Pick-n-Pull is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Achieving Current Balance between two PSUs**

The key question is how you control the voltage output of the two supplies in a way which causes them to share the load equally.

There are two main ways to do this: active and passive load sharing.

With active load sharing, you typically share a signal between PSUs such as conversion frequency or duty cycle.  This can be master-slave, or active-active with open drain drivers.  The PSUs then ramp their output in sync to give roughly equal sharing of load. *However, this is only possible with supplies explicitly designed for paralleling.*

With passive load sharing, you use output "droop", where the voltage of the supply drops according to load.  Assuming good initial alignment of output voltages, this automatically shares the load, because if one supply has slightly higher voltage, it will draw more current until the droop cancels out the difference leading to approximate load sharing.

Even if the supplies are "stiff", with little droop, you can make them suitable for load sharing by explicitly adding a resistance in series with each output.  This wastes power, but may be unavoidable in this case.

So in summary, you need to find out accuracy of the voltage outputs (under a range of conditions including temperature and supply voltage), and the droop characteristics (commonly expressed as mV/A, but equivalent to R).  You then need to decide if the inherent droop is enough to achieve the required balance, or if you need to add extra series resistance.

Answer (score 1):

If two power supplies are shunted on the output and are not designed for stability, caused by external noise at any load range, and it can oscillate.

If the design is such that it only pulls up voltage under load and not down if over voltage, then simply having one regulator slightly higher, will make the other one idle most of the time for you to have redundant power but not for current sharing.

There may be other issues to consider before making a choice and verifying that power interruption or sequencing, or any step load, will not induce damage on the other supply.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this before with isolated supplies to provide more output current, the voltage needs to be (mostly) the same on both supplies. Because of small voltage differences between supplies a series resistor on the outputs of both supplies can provide current balancing, usually in small values lower than 1 Ohm but it depends on the current and the potential voltage difference of the isolated supplies.

Paralleling the outputs of POE supplies will be problematic. The problem will come with the power being sourced by the supplies, as POE power is negotiated by the controller. It's likely that the controller might not negotiate the power especially during the power sequence that POE uses to determine the class with both supplies being tied together.

Comment: Yeah; not a concern in the topology I was suggesting, as the two supplies would share a PD controller.